# Upper part of desktop cut off on a Panasonic VIERA TC-P50X3 50-Inch 720p television

Tags: 11.04, nvidia

Ubuntu displays the upper 2/3-3/4 of the desktop only.  Top panel is partially off screen and lower panel is way off screen.  Video card is Nvidia GF FX 5200 AGP 8x.

It's older and replaced a GF 6200 which blew some caps.  I can't figure out xserver settings to make t.v. work as in fit within screen to see all of desktop.  I've tried without 3D drivers, with them [173 Recommended] and with Experimental Nouveax...  Neither of those video cards seemed very adaptable to the situation of using Xserver settings.

Tried twin view and other setting. The more I worked with it the more it got messed up until both panels are not visible.  Don't know what else to say except thanx for any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

in my case I hade to change the display settings on my TV ( SAMSUNG UE40D6505)

Comment: Could you please add more detail (you can use the 'edit' link below your answer)?